# How to uninstall ghdl installed from source?

Tags: arch-linux, make

I installed ghdl version 0.36 from source.
Output of make -n install

```
➜  ghdl-0.36 make -n install
mkdir -p /usr/local
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/ghdl
mkdir -p /usr/local/include
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o jumps.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/config/jumps.c
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o times.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/config/times.c
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o grt-cbinding.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/grt-cbinding.c
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o grt-cvpi.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/grt-cvpi.c
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o fstapi.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/fst/fstapi.c
-I/home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/fst
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o lz4.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/fst/lz4.c
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o fastlz.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/fst/fastlz.c
gcc -c -g -o memsegs_c.o src/ortho/mcode/memsegs_c.c
gcc -c -g -DWITH_GNAT_RUN_TIME -o chkstk.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/config/chkstk.S
if test -d ./.git \
   && desc=`cd .; git describe --dirty`; then \
          sub="s/[(].*[)]/($desc)/"; \
else \
  sub="s/tarball/tarball/"; \
        fi; \
sed -e "$sub" -e "s/@VER@/0.36/" < src/version.in > version.tmp; \

if [ ! -r version.ads ] || ! cmp version.tmp version.ads > /dev/null; then cp version.tmp version.ads; fi
gnatmake -o ghdl_mcode -aI./src -aI./src/vhdl -aI./src/grt -aI./src/psl -aI./src/vhdl/translate -aI./src/ghdldrv -aI./src/ortho -aI./src/ortho/mcode -gnaty3befhkmr -gnatwa -gnatf -g -gnata -gnatwe -gnatw.A ghdl_jit.adb -bargs -E -largs memsegs_c.o chkstk.o jumps.o times.o grt-cbinding.o grt-cvpi.o fstapi.o lz4.o fastlz.o   -ldl -lm -Wl,--version-script=/home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/grt.ver -Wl,--export-dynamic
install -m 755 ghdl_mcode /usr/local/bin/ghdl
for d in src/std src/synopsys std/v87 ieee/v87 synopsys/v87 std/v93 ieee/v93 synopsys/v93 std/v08 ieee/v08 src/ieee src/vital95 src/vital2000 src/mentor src/ieee2008 mentor/v93 synopsys/v08; do
\
  mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/ghdl/$d; \
  install -m 644 -p \
    lib/ghdl/$d/* /usr/local/lib/ghdl/$d; \
done
install -m 644 -p \
    ./dist/ansi_color.sh /usr/local/lib/ghdl/;
mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/ghdl/vendors
install -m 644 -p \
    ./libraries/vendors/* /usr/local/lib/ghdl/vendors/
install -m 755 -p \
    ./libraries/vendors/*.sh /usr/local/lib/ghdl/vendors/
gcc -c -o vpi_thunk.o /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/vpi_thunk.c -fPIC -O -Wall
gcc -o libghdlvpi.so vpi_thunk.o -shared -Wl,-soname,libghdlvpi.so
install -m 755 -p libghdlvpi.so /usr/local/lib/
install -m 644 -p /home/hari/Downloads/ghdl-0.36/./src/grt/vpi_user.h /usr/local/include/
```

I however am facing some issues and wish install an older version. How do I go about doing that? Can I just remove binaries from /usr/local ?

OS: 5.2.8-arch1-1-ARCH

Answer (score 0):

What about `make uninstall`?

And why not using `makepkg` to create a package and then install it? [Here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?K=ghdl) are some PKGBUILDs for ghdl on AUR.